# how to change date format from M/D/Y to D/M/Y after saving in database?

Tags: asp-classic

how to change date format from M/D/Y to D/M/Y after saving in database ?
I have saved a date to Data base with MM/D/YYYY format 
is there a way to return it in D/MM/YYY Format ??

Comment: not much to go by on here, could use a few more details. Showing what you have so far would be a good place to start :) Please update your question with the code you want and maybe a real life example of what you want the end result to look like.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to ensure the global location of your page is set to the UK format.

```
<%
Session.lcid=2057 '= UK English
%>
```